# Does using a destructured object as function arguments make sense?

Tags: javascript

Once upon a time we did this

```
/**
 * Function that does lots of things
 * @param {boolean} state
 * @param {number} max
 * @param {string} set
 * @param {number} timeout
 * @param {boolean} bail
 * @param {string} name
 * @param {function} cb
 */
function doLotsOfThings(state, max, set, timeout, bail, name, cb){

}
```

Then we were like, that doesn't look good. Do this.

```
/**
 * Function that does lots of things
 * @param {object} options
 * @param {number} options.max
 * @param {string} options.set
 * @param {number} options.timeout
 * @param {boolean} options.bail
 * @param {string} options.name
 * @param {function} options.cb
 */
function doLotsOfThings(options){

}
```

But now we doing this

```
/**
 * Function that does lots of things
 * @param {object} param
 * @param {number} param.max
 * @param {string} param.set
 * @param {number} param.timeout
 * @param {boolean} param.bail
 * @param {string} param.name
 * @param {function} param.cb
 */
function doLotsOfThings({max, set, timeout, bail, name, cb}){

}
```

Which is actually two characters more than we started with. Did we come full circle, or is this unintended use of the feature?    ..........................

Comment: Why are we doing `doLotsOfThings(Options)`? I guess it’s easier to handle defaults, prevent erroneous parameter combinations or support persistence of options. If we still need the simple approach, it is just two characters longer, but we still abstracted away the option handling.

Comment: Its depend on what output you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

As always, ***it depends***

If the object you are passing as a parameter (the “options” object) is commonly used across the application, possibly being used to call different functions, the unstructured approach can be useful.

However, if you need to create a specific object to call each of the “doLotsOfThings” functions, it probably isn't worth it and just using old-school parameters could be better.